# Ajax in laravel 5.1 to store an Entity MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: ajax, laravel, post

I'm having problems trying store data in laravel making an ajax Request.
I have a good route.

```
Route::post('system/match_events/store','Match_eventsController@store');
```

My controller has the store method:

```
public function store(Match_eventRequest $request)
{

    $params = $request->all();
    $match_event = new Match_event($params);
    $match_event->save();

    return 'true';
}
```

The javascript is this:

```
postData = { 
    _token: $('#form-hack input[name=_token]').val(), 
    player_id: "1",
    match_event_type_id: "1",
    match_id: "1",
    team_id: "2",
};
$.post("{{ url('/system/match_events/store') }}", postData)
    .fail(function(data) { 
    alert("There was an error with saving data: " );
});
```

But it's returning 
MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: Try dropping the slash at the beginning of the URL - it shouldn't need it when you are building it with the helper: `{{ url('system/match_events/store') }}`

Answer (score 0):

You shall see the request path in the Networks tab in your Browser

If you do this  using helper

```
{{ url('/system/match_events/store') }}
```

then the request would be

```
yourappname.com//system/match_events/store
```

Which would not exist on your route

So remove the `/`  in the url parameter and have like

```
{{ url('system/match_events/store') }}
```

**Tip :**

You shall debug this yourself by adjusting the url from ajax request by seeing the Networks Tab near to your Console

Hope this helps you

Comment: No. The problem is other. 

I tried before with a get and just returning a view and works well. Maybe to paste the code here I used an old version but it was already fixed when I post.